# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `opacity` of type `object` supplied to `Image`, expected `number`

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, react-native-animatable

While running jest I am getting this strange warning stating

```
console.error node_modules/fbjs/lib/warning.js:33
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `opacity` of type `object` supplied to `Image`, expected `number`.
Bad object: {
  "position": "absolute",
  "top": 40,
  "right": 24,
  "opacity": {
    "_children": [],
    "_value": 0.5,
    "_startingValue": 0.5,
    "_offset": 0,
    "_animation": null,
    "_listeners": {}
  }
}
    in Image
```

and my actaul component code is the following

```
<Animated.Image
    source={require('../loginUserPicture.png')}
    style={[
       styles.loginUserPicture,
       {
           opacity: animatedOpacity,
           transform: [{
               scale: animateUserIcon
           }]
        }
    ]}
/>
```

Could anyone help me in getting rid of this warning. From the waning message I can see that the test framework is not recognizing the Animated value.

It is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation and seems like no one else is getting this warning. Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: To get a better answer please add your code of failing test and how you set `animatedOpacity`.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I am just rendering the app `renderer.create(<App />).toJSON();` Running with the default config and mocks. I could not find any proper guide on this topic. If we need to pass or mock Animated object please let me know how to do it.